# Trying to add multiple image in a single row

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, oracle

I am trying to insert multiple images in a single row in a field in oracle database, please suggest how to achieve it. Below are the details
image is rendering on the  browser and I want to store multiple image through it in oracle db. Each image will have an id generating dynamically

aspx code:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <style>        
             input[type="file"] {

             display:block;
            }
            .imageThumb {
             max-height: 75px;
             border: 2px solid;
             margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
             padding: 1px;
             }
                 </style>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    Find the bellow HTML code
                    <h2>preview multiple images before upload using jQuery</h2>
                    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" BorderColor="#CCFF66"   
ForeColor="#0066FF"  Text="Insert Data" />  
                </form>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
        var a = 0;
                        if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
                            $("#files").on("change", function (e) {
                                var files = e.target.files,
                                filesLength = files.length;
        if (filesLength == 1) {                        
                                a = a + 1;
                            }
                                for (var i = 0; i < filesLength ; i++) {
                                    var f = files[i]
                                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                                    fileReader.onload = (function (e) {
                                        var file = e.target;
                                        $("<img></img>", {
                                            class: "imageThumb",
        Id: "img"+ a.toString(),
                                            src: e.target.result,
                                            title: file.name
                                        }).insertAfter("#files");
                                    });
                                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
                                }
                            });
                        } else { alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API") }
                    });
                </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

for saving image into oracle db I am using ajax and created webservice to push data into db:

```
[WebMethod]
         public static void SaveUser(User user)
            {
         String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString;
                using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO par_cinfo(Product_Id,IMAGETYPE ) VALUES (:IMAGETYPE )", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IMAGETYPE ", user.IMAGETYPE);
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();               
                        con.Close();
                    }
          }
            }

        }

        public class User
        {
        public decimal Product_Id { get; set; }
            public Image IMAGETYPE { get; set; }

        }
```

jQuery ajax on button click to send data to webservices:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $("[id*=Button3]").bind("click", function () {
                var user = {};
                user.Product_Id = 1;
                user.IMAGETYPE= "here dynamic image id which is uploaded should be present "
     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/SaveUser",
                    data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                    //data: JSON.stringify({user:user}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("User has been added successfully.");
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The table which I created in oracle is as follows simply for entering the data in the table:

```
  Create table par_cinfo
             (
              Product_Id         NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
              IMAGETYPE          BLOB    
              )
```

Comment: if each image is different, and is to have a separate ID then each one should be on separate rows, not in the same row. The database should generate the unique ID for you using an auto increment primary key field. If you need to relate them all to a specific user, then add another column User ID with a foreign key to your user table. Also your upload code isn't going to work - but you can easily google many examples of how to upload binary file data using ajax.

Comment: Or, just don't use ajax - since you just refresh the page immediately after ajax finishes, why not use a normal postback? The whole point of ajax is to avoid having to refresh the page. If you're not going to avoid that, then don't bother yourself with the extra complexity caused by using ajax.

Comment: There is a full implementation of your exact code with C# codebehind right here: http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/755566/Upload-and-preview-images-and-save-in-Database-using-C-VBNet-and-jQuery-in-ASPNet/ Hope this helps.